# Looking for guidance in creating a address control C#

Tags: c#

I am looking to create an application that will query for address information (first, last, address, city, state, zip). A custom Address Windows control you can use in any application. This control needs to validate zip code and that all fields are properly filled in. I am looking for some tutorials that can help or any guidance On how to create this type of control.

Comment: Maybe you could add some code stub about what you require? Do you need a form control that you can drop into a window? (This question will not go too well here)

Comment: The control would be as a be as a public class I am assuming but am not finding much on this type of control in my student handbook. It would  be placed in a windows form application and the class would be called upon when user clicks to submit data. Sorry if the placement of the question is improper was just hoping for some experienced guidance.

Comment: Would you be able to implement something like this in a form? If this is the case just create a UserControl instead of a Winform app in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider creating an Address model class that defines the data you are collecting. Individual properties of the class can be bound to the values of controls in your usercontrol gui.

This class can implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) interfaces to help it interact with the windows forms data binding components.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Francesco suggests create a user control. It is essentially a **compound** or **composite** control. For address you can add the required text and label controls and maybe the logic to validate them. Then you can reuse this across projects.

Add a class into your windows forms project like this:

```
public class AddressForm : UserControl
{
 //excluding this causes probs with VS designer sometimes.
 public AddressForm() : base() 
 {
 }
}
```

Build your project and you will notice the file icon in visual studio changes, when you double click it you can then design the control by adding simple controls on it.

Make sure you build after any change, and you should also see the toolbox updated when you're designing a form. `AddressForm` will show up there and you can drag and add it on the form. It is now officially reusable.

See [msdn on UserControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) for more. Try and run their customer form sample (on the same page) and you should have a good idea.